# async.js how to repeat a series until an unexpected error occurs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Is there a way to repeat a series of tasks until an unexpected error occurs in [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)?

Something like this

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        // do stuff
    },
    function(callback) {
        // do more stuff
    },
    function(callback) {
        // do even more stuff
    },
    function(callback) {
        // more more more
    }
], function(error, results) {

    if(error.message.search(/ESOCKETTIMEDOUT|ETIMEDOUT/) == -1) {
        // stop here
    } else {
        // repeat series
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```
void function loop() {
  async.series([
      function(callback) {
          // do stuff
      },
      function(callback) {
          // do more stuff
      },
      function(callback) {
          // do even more stuff
      },
      function(callback) {
          // more more more
      }
  ], function(error, results) {
      if (error && error.message.search(/ESOCKETTIMEDOUT|ETIMEDOUT/) == -1) {
        // stop here
      } else {
        loop();
      }
  });
}();
```

Comment: @Aley how does it work? Did it solve the problem or you implement something else or in another way?

Comment: Indeed it did. I thougth there is an implementation in async.js, but this solutions works as expected.